# display date in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

trying to teach myself javascript. However, I cannot figure out why the following code doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

    <p> Click the button to display the date</p>

    <button onclick="showDate()">HIT ME</button>

    <script>
        function displayDate()
        {
          document.getElementById("test").innterHTML=displayDate();   
        }
    </script>

    <p id="test"></p>
</body>
```

copy and pasted it wrong, here is the actual code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

    <p> Click the button to display the date</p>

    <button onclick="showDate()">HIT ME</button>

    <script>
        function showDate()
        {
          document.getElementById("test").innterHTML=Date();   
        }
    </script>

    <p id="test"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Your `onclick` function is not named the same as the function you created in the `script` tag below. There are many problems with this code. How are you trying to learn javascript?

Comment: You just did a [recursive function](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-lesson-205/0/1): your function is calling _itself_, leading to an endless loop. --> Except that `displayDate()` is never actually _called_, so it is not being executed.

Comment: onclick="showDate()" => where is function showDate() {...} ??

Comment: Your function `displayDate` is never called. But if it were, it would be calling itself and assigning the value it returns to the innerHTML property of element with id `test`. However, the function doesn't return anything, so nothing is actually set in that element. Furthermore, this creates an infinite loop, which is not what you wanted.

Comment: You are stuck in an infinite loop.You are stuck in an infinite loop.You are stuck in an infinite loop.You are stuck in an infinite loop.You are stuck in an infinite loop.You are stuck in an infinite loop.You are stuck in an infinite loop.You are stuck in an infinite loop.You are stuck in an infinite loop.You are stuck in an infinite loop.You are stuck in an infinite loop.You are stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: I just added the code I made. I'm trying to learn javascript via W3Schools and sometimes their code doesn't work when I try and do it myself.

Comment: Try http://www.codecademy.com/ for coding tutorials. I learned to code there!

Comment: Even though you've received answers, I'm voting to close because a question saying "here's some code, tell me why it doesn't work" is not useful. When I see a question saying "it doesn't work" without explaining *in which way* it doesn't work, I'll vote to close as "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem" or "unclear what you're asking" 9 times out of 9. "It doesn't work" doesn't give anyone a starting point for examining the problem. Explain what results you're getting and how they differ from the intended results, and include any error messages you received.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById("test").innterHTML=Date();
```

Should be

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=Date();
```

Answer (score 1):

There're multiple bugs in your code, i'll post a working one then explain you each of them

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
    function displayDate()
    {
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = Date();   
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p> Click the button to display the date</p>

<button onclick="displayDate()">HIT ME</button>


<p id="test"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

1. First thing is the recursive call of them displayDate() function. The function calls itself without any condition and eventually end up with stack overflow (we all like this isn't it)
2. Another problem is you bind your button on click event handler to "showData()" which is a function does not exist at all. (well you updated your original code I can see. just outlining it anyways)
3. All script in body are load and executed as the browser sees it, so it's better practice to keep them in the head section, if not a separate file
4. You have a typo on "innerHTML"

Answer (score 0):

First of all you had innterHTML, which should be innerHTML
Second of all You are looping a function, bad practice.
For info on date see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp; 
If you would want a loop then use `setInterval(function() {/* Action*/},100 /* Delay*/)`. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp.
(If you have a problem see W3Schools in general)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

    <p> Click the button to display the date</p>

    <button onclick="showDate()">HIT ME</button>

    <script>

        function displayDate()
        {
          document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=new Date().getTime() // Display timestamp
        }
    </script>

    <p id="test"></p>
</body>
```